# Why is CodedUI TestMap very slow in Remote Desktop?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I am using `VSTS 2012` for UI Automation on client machine which is connected through VMware.

The problem is with UI Test map. Whenever I try to capture or locate an object, VSTS takes long time to locate it. This is terribly consuming time.

Can someone please assist on how to overcome or this is something to do with VSTS behaviour?

Please assist ASAP.

Regards,

Comment: Is it slow when recording tests or when running them. As Rajesh says, UI maps can get very large and that can be a cause of slow behaviour. Do a web search for "multiple ui maps".

Comment: I have the exact same problem, except I did not try working locally, so only via rdp session - since I work from hyper-v. I noticed initially it seemed to be ok, but now it is drastically slow can take up to 3-4 minutes to identify a control.

Comment: Well I tried it through local hyper-v and it recognised controls almost instantly, so it would seem it it an issue only over rdc - nice find Nazeer. Very strange and can't offer a solution at this time.

Comment: Also tried it using VNC and just as quick. I have to check if it is possible to connect via rdp using "console mode".

Answer (score 1):

Start the remote session using this command:

```
mstsc /console.
```

You still get all the benefits like dynamic screen resolution, but control identification will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I too came across this issue.
Im my experience, it was because of **more number of controls** been added in UIMap. If so, just create **another UIMap** and move some controls to the another UIMap.
I would like to hear from you after trying this. :)

Comment: Rajessh, Let me make my problem more precise. The slow responsiveness of VSTS is during object capturing itself. I hardly added 10 objects to a single UI Map. This problem doesn't persist if I work from my local desktop but the problem is while using remote desktop.